# How to get the USB serial number in C++ and Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, serial-port, libusb

I would like to be able to read the serial number associated to my USB devices.

```
[89185.825492 <   68.912895>] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 41 using xhci_hcd
[89185.975679 <    0.150187>] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=03eb, idProduct=2404, bcdDevice= 1.00
[89185.975685 <    0.000006>] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[89185.975689 <    0.000004>] usb 1-4: Product: USB Roboclaw 2x30A
[89185.975692 <    0.000003>] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Basicmicro Inc.
[89185.975695 <    0.000003>] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 260
[89185.977910 <    0.002215>] cdc_acm 1-4:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

In this case, the serial number to read is 260.

I can't understand how can I get such value after opening the port.
This is the code used to open the serial communication:

```
#include "TimeoutSerial.h"
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

TimeoutSerial::TimeoutSerial(): io(), port(io), timer(io),
                                timeout(boost::posix_time::seconds(0)) {}

TimeoutSerial::TimeoutSerial(const std::string& devname, unsigned int baud_rate,
                             asio::serial_port_base::parity opt_parity,
                             asio::serial_port_base::character_size opt_csize,
                             asio::serial_port_base::flow_control opt_flow,
                             asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits opt_stop)
        : io(), port(io), timer(io), timeout(boost::posix_time::seconds(0))
{
    open(devname,baud_rate,opt_parity,opt_csize,opt_flow,opt_stop);
}

void TimeoutSerial::open(const std::string& devname, unsigned int baud_rate,
                         asio::serial_port_base::parity opt_parity,
                         asio::serial_port_base::character_size opt_csize,
                         asio::serial_port_base::flow_control opt_flow,
                         asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits opt_stop)
{
    if(isOpen()) close();
    port.open(devname);
    port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(baud_rate));
    port.set_option(opt_parity);
    port.set_option(opt_csize);
    port.set_option(opt_flow);
    port.set_option(opt_stop);

}

bool TimeoutSerial::isOpen() const
{
    return port.is_open();
}

void TimeoutSerial::close()
{
    if(isOpen()==false) return;
    port.close();
}

void TimeoutSerial::setTimeout(const boost::posix_time::time_duration& t)
{
    timeout=t;
}

void TimeoutSerial::write(const char *data, size_t size)
{
    asio::write(port,asio::buffer(data,size));
}

void TimeoutSerial::write(const std::vector<char>& data)
{
    asio::write(port,asio::buffer(&data[0],data.size()));
}

void TimeoutSerial::writeString(const std::string& s)
{
    asio::write(port,asio::buffer(s.c_str(),s.size()));
}

void TimeoutSerial::read(char *data, size_t size)
{
    if(readData.size()>0)//If there is some data from a previous read
    {
        istream is(&readData);
        size_t toRead=min(readData.size(),size);//How many bytes to read?
        is.read(data,toRead);
        data+=toRead;
        size-=toRead;
        if(size==0) return;//If read data was enough, just return
    }

    setupParameters=ReadSetupParameters(data,size);
    performReadSetup(setupParameters);

    //For this code to work, there should always be a timeout, so the
    //request for no timeout is translated into a very long timeout
    if(timeout!=boost::posix_time::seconds(0)) timer.expires_from_now(timeout);
    else timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::hours(100000));

    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&TimeoutSerial::timeoutExpired,this,
                                 asio::placeholders::error));

    result=resultInProgress;
    bytesTransferred=0;
    for(;;)
    {
        io.run_one();
        switch(result)
        {
            case resultSuccess:
                timer.cancel();
                return;
            case resultTimeoutExpired:
                port.cancel();
                throw(timeout_exception("Timeout expired"));
            case resultError:
                timer.cancel();
                port.cancel();
                throw(boost::system::system_error(boost::system::error_code(),
                                                  "Error while reading"));
                //if resultInProgress remain in the loop
        }
    }
}

std::vector<char> TimeoutSerial::read(size_t size)
{
    vector<char> result(size,'\0');//Allocate a vector with the desired size
    read(&result[0],size);//Fill it with values
    return result;
}

std::string TimeoutSerial::readString(size_t size)
{
    string result(size,'\0');//Allocate a string with the desired size
    read(&result[0],size);//Fill it with values
    return result;
}

std::string TimeoutSerial::readStringUntil(const std::string& delim)
{
    // Note: if readData contains some previously read data, the call to
    // async_read_until (which is done in performReadSetup) correctly handles
    // it. If the data is enough it will also immediately call readCompleted()
    setupParameters=ReadSetupParameters(delim);
    performReadSetup(setupParameters);

    //For this code to work, there should always be a timeout, so the
    //request for no timeout is translated into a very long timeout
    if(timeout!=boost::posix_time::seconds(0)) timer.expires_from_now(timeout);
    else timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::hours(100000));

    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&TimeoutSerial::timeoutExpired,this,
                                 asio::placeholders::error));

    result=resultInProgress;
    bytesTransferred=0;
    for(;;)
    {
        io.run_one();
        switch(result)
        {
            case resultSuccess:
            {
                timer.cancel();
                bytesTransferred-=delim.size();//Don't count delim
                istream is(&readData);
                string result(bytesTransferred,'\0');//Alloc string
                is.read(&result[0],bytesTransferred);//Fill values
                is.ignore(delim.size());//Remove delimiter from stream
                return result;
            }
            case resultTimeoutExpired:
                port.cancel();
                throw(timeout_exception("Timeout expired"));
            case resultError:
                timer.cancel();
                port.cancel();
                throw(boost::system::system_error(boost::system::error_code(),
                                                  "Error while reading"));
                //if resultInProgress remain in the loop
        }
    }
}

TimeoutSerial::~TimeoutSerial() {}

void TimeoutSerial::performReadSetup(const ReadSetupParameters& param)
{
    if(param.fixedSize)
    {
        asio::async_read(port,asio::buffer(param.data,param.size),boost::bind(
                &TimeoutSerial::readCompleted,this,asio::placeholders::error,
                asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    } else {
        asio::async_read_until(port,readData,param.delim,boost::bind(
                &TimeoutSerial::readCompleted,this,asio::placeholders::error,
                asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}

void TimeoutSerial::timeoutExpired(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(!error && result==resultInProgress) result=resultTimeoutExpired;
}

void TimeoutSerial::readCompleted(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                                  const size_t bytesTransferred)
{
    if(!error)
    {
        result=resultSuccess;
        this->bytesTransferred=bytesTransferred;
        return;
    }

    //In case a asynchronous operation is cancelled due to a timeout,
    //each OS seems to have its way to react.
#ifdef _WIN32
    if(error.value()==995) return; //Windows spits out error 995
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
    if(error.value()==45)
    {
        //Bug on OS X, it might be necessary to repeat the setup
        //http://osdir.com/ml/lib.boost.asio.user/2008-08/msg00004.html
        performReadSetup(setupParameters);
        return;
    }
#else //Linux
    if(error.value()==125) return; //Linux outputs error 125
#endif

    result=resultError;
}
```

Is there any chance to get the serialnumber value?

Comment: You already read the data. You have the stuff you want. All you need is to parse the data you got to extract the detail you need. Asking "Is there any chance to get the serialnumber value?" Gets the answer "Yes of course there is - if you can manage to parse it out of the data". What other answer did you expect?

Comment: Probably not from the device but from somewhere in /sys/bus/usb. Remember not all serial ports are USB devices. Find the USB device that corresponds to your serial port, then get its serial number. I think in /sys/bus/usb is enough information to find which one is the same device since it has the device file number

Comment: This is shown by `lsusb`. So, just grab it's source and see what it does?

Comment: Serial ports and USB devices are two mostly separate worlds. Only USB-based virtual serial ports have a serial number. I recommend to use [libusbp](https://github.com/pololu/libusbp). It can list virtual serial ports. Once you have a match, you can use one of its USB functions to query the serial number.

Comment: I'm using a RS232-to-USB adapter, however, probably, I wasn't able to explain clearly what is the problem. Nevermind. I'll find a solution by myself.